# A Revelation (?) from MS Word

Tags: word-order

So, I typed the parenthetic statement 'Asked why did he come here'. Microsoft Word suggested that I change the sentence to 'Asked why he came here'. I agreed with the correction, but when I had word explain the change, the following came up:

Order of Words
If your sentence includes a statement about a question rather than a direct question, the subject should come before the verb.

It then went on to give these examples:

Instead of: He asked the bus driver when would the next bus come.
Consider: He asked the bus driver when the next bus would come.

Instead of: I wonder what did they serve for lunch.
Consider: I wonder what they served for lunch.

Now, I agree with the change to my sentence. It seems 'better sounding' and less awkward, and I thought that if I really wanted to keep the did, maybe the sentence would be better written: Asked 'why did you come here?'. But in the examples Word gives the subject comes before the verb in both the erroneous and correct versions.

Was Word on to an actual grammatical rule, and if so, could someone clear it up for me?

Comment: “Asked why *did* he come here, John had no answer for the officer.”

Comment: @Jim No, that is not the point. The point is that inserting a stressed ***did*** where I did so is a valid although uncommon technique. It is asking a question with a considerably different emphasis.

Comment: Or, to put it into the sequence of tenses, "Asked why **he had come** here, John had no answer ..."

Comment: @tchrist- Ok, I understand your point and I agree, stressing *did* is valid and changes the implication of the question. We so often use *italics* to point out a word that I did not interpret your italics as spoken emphasis.

Comment: The simple rule is that subject-auxiliary inversion happens in main clause questions, but not in embedded questions. There's a footnote to the effect that, if you intend the embedded question to act like a real question and elicit an answer, you can go ahead and invert (but not in this case, because it's past tense).

Comment: @Jim: Since you claim to understand tchrist's weird sentence & he hasn't bothered to explain how & why such awkwardness is "valid" or what contexts this "uncommon technique" is appropriate for, perhaps you will be kind enough to explain rather than merely asking us to read your collective minds. Stress is one thing in spoken English, but the example sentence isn't spoken English, it's written English, **reported speech**, &, IMHO, totally off the wall: where are the quotation marks? **What** implication is changed? Good mysteries (Sherlock Holmes) are fun; unsolved ones aren't.

Comment: Here are two websites that give the rules about question word order in English. They illustrate John Lawler's comment. [British Council](http://snurl.com/270y827) & [LinguaPress](http://snurl.com/270y86p). "I wonder, 'What did they serve for lunch?'" takes "do-support" because it's a direct Q & any content word can be stressed; "I wonder what they served for lunch" is normal. Word was definitely onto a legit grammar rule.

Comment: @BillFranke Professor Lawler already explained it in his footnote. You need to stay awake in class.

Comment: A big thank you to all the participants in this 'debate'. It's been illuminating. I especially want to thank Mr. Franke for the resources he provided. I've instantly bookmarked them.

Comment: @tchrist: I understand Prof Lawler's comment. Your cursory muddling remarks are merely mystifying & inaccurate. You need to be clear rather than complacent when you offer your petite pearls.

Answer (score 0):

MS Word is consistent and correct. The (finite) verbs in the versions it suggested are **would** and **served/did**, and those come after the subject in normal statements and indirect questions, but not in direct questions. You used the inverted word order as used in questions, where you should have used normal word order, as Word suggested.

> Instead of: <s>I wonder what **did** *they* serve for lunch.</s> Consider: I wonder what *they* **served** for lunch.

A normal statement has normal word order:

> *They* **served** bread for lunch.

A normal, direct question has inversion of subject and finite verb:

> What **did** *they* serve for lunch?

You can, however, turn your indirect question into a direct question, by using quotation marks, as you suggested:

> I wonder, "what **did** *they* serve for lunch"?

Somewhat less formally, you can leave out the quotation marks; but you should *never* leave out the comma.